# Django-mongodb check boolean in raw_query

Tags: django, mongodb

How to check if a boolean is set to true in a raw_query using django-mongodb.

I'm looking for the equivalent of mongodb's: {'is_bool': true}. I tried:

```
collection.raw_query({'is_bool': True}) 
# Raises an Exception: 'ObjectId' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

collection.raw_query({'is_bool': 'true'}) 
# Checks if the is_bool is string 'true', so doesn't work either
```

Comment: Please paste the complete traceback for #1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made a mistake. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, my bad!

```
collection.raw_query({'is_bool': True})
```

Is working, but the exception I got was caused by a faulty value in the db.